# Strange compiler error when calling required initializer on generic type parameter

Tags: core-data, swift3, xcode8

Does anyone know why the first function compiles correctly, while the second one fails? Is this some sort of bug of the Swift 3 compiler?

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

protocol P {
    init?(i: Int)
}


class C {
    func f<T: NSObject>(i: Int) -> T? where T: P {
        return T(i: i)  // compiles OK
    }

    func g<T: NSManagedObject>(i: Int) -> T? where T: P {
        return T(i: i)  // doesn't compile: "Incorrect argument label in call
                 ^      // (have: 'i:', expected 'context:')
    }
}
```